# Typescript shaping: What is the meaning of each section of this Next.js component?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js

Let's take this function, for example:

```
interface IParams extends ParsedUrlQuery {
    id: string
}

interface Props {
  params: {
    id: string;
  };
}

export const getStaticProps: GetStaticProps<IParams> = async ({ params: { id } }: Props) => {
  const { data: lesson } = await supabase
    .from("lesson")
    .select("*")
    .eq("id", id)
    .single();

  return {
    props: {
      lesson,
    },
  };
};
```

When we review this signature:

```
export const getStaticProps: GetStaticProps<IParams> = async ({ params: { id } }: Props) => { ... }
```

What is the first `<IParams>` shape defining? Is this the input of the getStaticProps function, or its output?

If I have `<IParams>` specified, do I need the "Props" shape?

What defines the shape of the output using this example?

Comment: The first <IParams> shape is defining the input of the getStaticProps function. The Props shape is not necessary, but it is used to provide type safety for the parameters being passed into the function. The shape of the output is defined by the return statement, which is returning an object with a "props" property containing a "lesson" property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's start with `GetStaticProps<FirstShape, SecondShape>` and the dynamic page `[id].js.`

The first shape is the return type of `getStaticProps,` which should also match the prop type for the page.

The second shape is the query params for `getStaticProps.`

---

Since the query param is `id` (defined by the file name) will be passed in query params. However, it could also be `undefined,` so you must account for that.

[id].js

```
import { GetStaticProps } from "next";
import { FC } from "react";

type PageProps = {
  yourData: any;
};

type QueryParams = {
  id: string;
};

const Page: FC<PageProps> = ({ yourData }) => {
  console.log(yourData);
  return <div>Page</div>;
};

export const getStaticProps: GetStaticProps<PageProps, QueryParams> = ({ params }) => {
  if(!params || params.id) {
    return { notFound: true };
  }
  return {
    props: {
      yourData: { id: params.id },
    },
  };
};

export default Page;
```

---

Based on your example, you'd have something like...

```
import { GetStaticProps } from "next";
import { FC } from "react";

type PageProps = {
  lesson: any // your lesson type
};

type QueryParams = {
  id: string;
};

const Page: FC<PageProps> = ({ lesson }) => {
  console.log(lesson);
  return <div>Page</div>;
};

export const getStaticProps: GetStaticProps<PageProps, QueryParams> = async ({
  params, // possibly undefined, don't destructure here
}) => {
  try {
    if (!params || params.id) throw Error("No id"); // throw error, so it goes to the catch statement to return notFound
    const { id } = params; // destructure after you know params is defined
    const { data, error } = await supabase.from("lesson").select("*").eq("id", id).single();
    if (!data || error) throw Error(error.message ?? "No data");
    return { props: { lesson: data } };
  } catch (e) {
    console.error(e);
    return { notFound: true };
  }
};

export default Page;
```

Comment: Thank you Sean, great explanation -- could I ask a follow up question... how do I destructure "id" keeping everything else the same in your example? I can't get this part to work properly and it's killing me.

Comment: I added comments and destructing inside the code block. I'm guessing you're trying to destructure params, but it's possibly undefined, so you're running into trouble with TS. You need to wait to destructure until you know `params` is set. There are ways around this, but they are hacky.